# Error While Adding Script Tag into Saber Static Site Generator

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I am trying to manipulate the head of my website using the head attribute inside of the export default function on my post layout inside of my Saber Vue.js static site generated website (https://saber.land).  Whenever I try to add in my script tag and the Adsense code using the head attribute, none of the main.js code is running.  I know that an error is happening because the title of the website changes from the formatted one to the exact URL of the website.  Here is my post.vue (layout) script tag code:

```
import 'prismjs/themes/prism-twilight.css'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar.vue'
import Footer from '../components/Footer.vue'

export default {
    components: {
        Navbar,
        Footer
    },
    props: ['page'],
    head() {
        return {
            title: `${this.page.title} - ${this.$siteConfig.title}`
        }
    },
    methods: {
        formatDate(v) {
        const date = new Date(v)
        return `${date.getMonth()+1}/${date.getDate()}/${date.getFullYear()}`
        }
    },
    head: {
      script: [{
        "src": "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js",
        "async": "true",
        "data-ad-client": "ca-pub-1485901785138606"
      }],
      script: [{
        "src": "/main.js"
      }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're adding the Adsense script at a component level and not at the vue-root level? Even your main.js should go there imo. What does `main.js` do even? Your JS functionality should be covered within saber/vue

Comment: It is in a layout not a component.  My main.js file configures the menu bars toggle button for the navigation links.  How would one go about covering the javascript functionality in saber/vue?  I tried to add a script tag into the layout inside of the <template> tag and it gave me an error saying I must not have tags that are going to modify the state of something.

Comment: It's a bit hard to figure, could you try and replicate you issue in codesandbox? You can fork this one - https://codesandbox.io/s/github/egoist/saber-codesandbox/tree/master/?from-embed

Comment: Here is all of the code for my project https://github.com/CodingCarter/CodingCarterWebsite